# Getting Bluetooth state by using monkeyrunner

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I am using monkeyrunner tool for automating Bluetooth testing as it works on UI level am not able to get Bluetooth state for validating my testcase after switching on. please tel me is it possible to get Bluetooth status by using monkeyrunner API's?

I tried one of adb command "adb shell Dumpsys Bluetooth" but this is working fine till 4.1 version but i need this for android 4.2. please tel me is there any other commands that will return Bluetooth service information for android 4.2.